# Is it normal for process ids in Linux to continually increment into the high thousands after a few weeks?

Tags: linux

I'm not an expert with Linux and have no idea how to begin debugging this issue or whether it's an issue at all.

I'm running a Linux server on a Windows machine (dual booting) and every few days running `ps aux` the process ids that get assigned get higher and higher. After about two weeks the process ids that get allocated are around 17,000.

Is this normal behavior?
I would've expected process ids to be reused.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is not a issue and is expected, normal behavior.

> “I'm not an expert with linux and have no idea how to begin debugging this issue or weather its an issue at all.”

It’s not an issue. Linux ids run up to a specified amount and then roll backs back to the beginning after reaching that maximum number. ]

You can check this from the terminal by running this command:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

The output I get on a an Ubuntu 16.04.5 server I manage is:

```
32768
```

As explained on the [`proc`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) man page:

> /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max (since Linux 2.5.34)
>
> This file specifies the value at which PIDs wrap around (i.e., the value in this file is one greater than the maximum PID). The default value for this file, 32768, results in the same range of PIDs as on earlier kernels. On 32-bit platforms, 32768 is the maximum value for pid_max. On 64-bit systems, pid_max can be set to any value up to 2^22 (PID_MAX_LIMIT, approximately 4 million).

And that number is not significant for 99% of usage cases since you would only need to be concerned if you are somehow running 32,768 simultaneous processes at once with no chance of termination; ain’t a common thing to happen and doubt it can be done for any practical reason.